# Doxygen: Having "Modules" twice in the Table of Content with Fortran Code

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I am currently documenting a F95/2003 software project with the help of doxygen. On the one hand I grouped corresponding pages with the help of `@defgroup`, `@addtogroup`, `@ingroup`.... which end up under the point **Modules** in the table of contents and the top menu. Then the project also contains Fortran Modules, properly documented, and they appear also as a separate **Modules** point in the table of contents, which makes them hard to distinguish. How can I rename one of them? Like naming the Module pages generated from the Fortran modules' documentation as **Fortran Modules** or the best option would be to get completely rid of the separate Modules pages for the Fortran modules, since they also belong to a doxygen group and can be found there asl well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle the "Fortran modules" are listed as namespaces, but by means of the `OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN = YES` the name is changed into "Modules". To get the correct naming is of course a difficult problem.

Doxygen has also the possibility to change, in respect to names and showing / hiding)  some layout elements, see the doxygen manual paragraph: "Changing the layout of pages" (http://doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout).

when creating a layout file say:

```
doxygen -l mylayout.xml
```

and changing here the line (approximately line 8):

```
<tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="">
```

into

```
<tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="Fortran Modules">
```

and setting in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile):

```
LAYOUT_FILE            = mylayout.xml
```

I think you get the effect you want to have.

The following I didn't try (so I don't know what the effect might be in your case, and I have big doubts but I mentioned it here for completeness as it came into my mind), but doxygen has also the `\namespace` command maybe you can use this in this case in stead of the grouping commands.

Comment: The "workaround" with the layout file works quite fine for my purpose. Thanks a lot.